# XML parsing in an Android application

Tags: java, android, xml

I wrote this code to parse an [XML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) string, but it did not work. There are no errors, but it did not give any output.

My XML string:

```
String xml = "<ArrayOfString>" + "<string>{" + "categoryId"+":1," +
    "Title" +":"+"Rock"+"," + "songs" +":" +" null}</string>" + "</ArrayOfString>";
```

The code:

```
    try {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = db.parse(xml);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        NodeList nodeList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ArrayOfString");

        item = new TextView[nodeList.getLength()];
        for (int i = 0; i < nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nodeList.item(i);
            item[i] = new TextView(this);

            Element fstElmnt = (Element) node;
            NodeList itemList = fstElmnt.getElementsByTagName("string");
            Element itemElement = (Element) itemList.item(0);
            itemList = itemElement.getChildNodes();
            item[i].setText("item = "
                            + ((Node) itemList.item(0)).getNodeValue());

            layout.addView(item[i]);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("XML Pasing Excpetion = " + e);
    }

    /** Set the layout view to display */
    setContentView(layout);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're calling [`DocumentBuilder.parse(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/parsers/DocumentBuilder.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) which is meant to accept a URL as its parameter, not the actual XML.

The simplest alternative is probably to use an `InputSource` reading from a `StringReader`:

```
StringReader reader = new StringReader(xml);
InputSource source = new InputSource(reader);
Document doc = db.parse(source);
```